# window.location doesn't work

Tags: jquery, window.location

This is my Code:

```
<div onclick="window.location = photo.php"></div>
```

But the url if I click on the div is:

```
http://www.domain.com/[object%20HTMLDivElement]
```

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Your div should be an anchor tag with `href="photo.php"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url needs to be a string:

```
<div onclick="window.location = 'photo.php'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

missing quotes in the value.

```
<div onclick="window.location = 'photo.php'"></div>
```